# Hive Streaming: Custom Map/Reducer with Combiner

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming, hiveql

I'm using custom map/reduce scripts written in python to do aggregation over a hive table (or the results of a hive query). The problem i'm having is that when the aggregate keys have skewed values, one reducer ends up with 15% of all the rows and takes 3-4 times longer than all the others.

To solve this i've written a combiner script. This works fine when calling through hadoop streaming and is performing as I would expect, however i cannot figure out how to use this combiner in hive. Here's what i've tried so far (in the map phase of the HQL)

*USING 'python mapper.py | sort | python combiner.py'*

This appears to do nothing - to test I replaced the last command with 'head -n 1' and it still returned the same number of rows - it looks like it's just running the mapper.py and ignoring everything after the pipe.

I've also tried various methods of nesting the commands, so having a FROM(...MAP..USING)  query and putting that as an input into another MAP/REDUCE USING query. This creates 2 stages as you would expect, however the first stage spawns reducers (which i wouldn't expect) and the reducer it's using is the same as the one defined for stage 2.

I tried the above query but added a REDUCE USING 'cat' to the subquery, that didn't seem to change the behaviour at all.

Any help you can give me on this would be appreciated. I would prefer to use hive rather than hadoop streaming because the input to this process (in some cases) is a hive view, also the output is written to a table and dynamically partitioned - i'll have to write separate steps to handle input/output for hadoop streaming.

Barring the combiner, does anyone have a good reason why when i put in USING 'python mapper.py | head -n 1' it does not return one row per mapper, as expected? If i can get the piped output working i can probably mirror the combiner logic.